# List indices must be integers or slices python 3.6 list

Tags: python, list, integer, slice

With my code I am trying to get user input to select a value in a array however it works when there is a fixed value such as 2 but when input() is mentioned it just doesnt work.

```
highstreet = ['tp' ,'io','fffffff','mmmmmm','ice']
x = input

highstreet[x]
print(highstreet[x])



 >> highstreet[x]
 >>TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not 
  builtin_function_or_method
```

Thanks

Comment: `x = input` assigns the function `input` to the variable `x`. If you want to _call_ the input function, and assign the result to `x`, you mean `x = input()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `input` is a `function` not a `variable`, thus you have to call first it in order to assign the value inputed to variable `x`. Even more, the error is very specific `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not builtin_function_or_method`, which means that variable `x` is a function, and this is because you assigned it a `function` in this case `input`.

```
x = int(input()) # int(raw_input()) in python 2


highstreet[x]
print(highstreet[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, input() returns a string value, not an integer. So, you need to cast it to int. Also, to store the result of highstreet[x], assign it to a variable and print it:

```
x = int(input())
value = highstreet[x]
print(value)
```